# C++ platform compatibility

Tags: c++

An object `foo` is written to a new file on platform 1 as:

```
write( file, &myFoo, sizeof(struct foo) );
```

...and then read on platform 2 using:

```
read(file, &myFoo, filesize(file) );
```

The `foo` object has the following definition:

```
struct foo
{
    char  a;
    int   b; 
    long  c;
    char* d;
};
```

What kind of issues might arise when loading `foo` on platform 2?

Comment: this sounds a lot like homework...

Comment: That the `Foo` may not have been properly written out as you didn't test for error returns from `write`. And a host of other issues, which have been addressed many times on SO.

Comment: this wasnt homework it was from my job interview test which I feel I completely bombed! I am just trying to go through all questions and figure out what I did wrong! Sorry!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you do this you need to watch out for:

- Data type sizes (`char` is the only one you can trust)
- Alignment / padding
- Endianness
- Pointing to invalid memory
- Floating point representation
- `ASCII` vs `EBCDIC` ? (yeah, seriously ?)
- **Probably others**

Comment: "char is the only one you can trust" - and that not in a useful way. `sizeof(char)` is 1, but if `CHAR_BIT` is 16 on platform 1, and 8 on platform 2, then something's got to give when the file is transferred from one system to the other. In practice, 16-bit-char systems probably don't have filesystems, and 9-bit systems are so ancient nobody cares, but in principle you can't trust even `char`...

Answer (score 12):

Every kind of issue!

We don't know if `char`, `int`, `long` or `char*` are the same size on different platforms.

And what happened to the stuff d pointed to?

There might also be padding between the members, which could differ between platforms. Big endian and little ending systems would store the bytes of integers and pointers in different order. If you are really unlucky, there might be a middle endian system as well.

Comment: He accepted this, without asking about middle endian?  Scary.

Comment: Laugh with other people, not at them. This is very close to being flagged. Was there really any need to be condescending? What value have you added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

i think, you have to use that pack pragma to ensure there are no padding.
otherwise char will have 4 bytes in size depending on the default padding method.

char* this address pointer can have 32bits on 32bit machine but 64bits on 64bit machine.
So store a pointer directly out is nonsense.

The last one is endian.